# Youtube API https Protocol

Tags: http, iframe, https, youtube-api

When I create an iframe player API using the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`, the link is created with the `http` protocol

Example:

```
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          width: '560',
          height: '600',
          videoId: '7j8B_r4OfAw',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }
```

iframe Result:

```
<iframe id="player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="560" height="600" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/7j8B_r4OfAw?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```

Does anyone know how to do the video to be created with the `https` protocol? Need to install the api on a platform.

Please, suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify https if you create the iframe element directly in your html, rather than using the div which gets replaced later on. You can create the iframe tag dynamically if you need to. Look at the bottom of [this section](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player), which spells out how to do it.

Beware — even if you load the player over https, the actual video stream may be served over http. That seems to cause a mixed-mode warning in Chrome, though not other browsers (in my experience last year; it may have since changed). See [this official blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/02/https-support-for-youtube-embeds.html), which explains that the player can be loaded over https but warns that the video still won't necessarily be served that way.