# How do I hack the YouTube JavaScript API to always use HTTP?

Tags: javascript, youtube

I am planning to do measurements on the network traffic when playing videos. This will of course only work when the video is transmitted over HTTP instead of HTTPS.

The YouTube iframe API however always switches to HTTPS downloads, despite me loading the API from `http://` and specifying a YouTube URL with `http://` too. You can use the [example here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) to test the player. As you can see it always switches to `https://videoplayback...`, which is what I want to disable.

How do I force it to use HTTP instead of HTTPS? This is sort of the [inverse question of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647455/youtube-api-https-protocol). I guess it would come down to hacking some functions into the current JS.

In the Widget API I can see calls like:

```
b = 0 == c.indexOf("https:") ? [c] : b.d ? [c.replace("http:", "https:")] : b.k ? [c] : [c, c.replace("http:", "https:")];
```

and

```
if (this.d = !!("https:" == document.location.protocol || a && 0 == a.src.indexOf("https:"))) {
    a = [this.j, window.YTConfig || {}, this.defaults];
    for (var b = 0; b < a.length; b++) a[b].host && (a[b].host = a[b].host.replace("http://", "https://"))
}
```

but I have no clue where to override this in the context of the `YT` and `YT.Player` objects, or if I can even do so.

To those wondering whether this might be impossible on the server-side: Note that YouTube *does* work with HTTP only. If you are not logged into YouTube and go to `http://youtube.com`, your video playbacks will be in HTTP, not HTTPS.

Comment: @sIhck you want only http no matter which API is called it should come from http by default ? is that your question Is ?

Comment: Yes, I want to force HTTP transmission.

Comment: @robert This question has nothing to do with a) downloading video or b) MP4 vs. MKV. YouTube does not even offer MKV as a downloadable option… but that's beside the point: This question is about embedding a YouTube player, and I'd like it to stream over HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Comment: @slhck if you have IDM you can download videos from youtube as MKV but it won't work as video with almost all video players look here to the first question 
`Sometimes IDM downloads MKV video files, which dont play good in my player. Can I download MP4 instead of MKV or what should I do to play MKV videos correctly? ` http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/register/new_faq/bi_main.cgi?mode=1

i read that you can download without MKV if you open chrome with http instead of https other browsers don't support MKV so the video play as default with MP4

Comment: @robert Please read again: **This question has nothing to do with downloading a video**. I don't know how you come to that conclusion.

Comment: i understand this has nothing to do i just told you why i thought about it

Comment: i don't think you will be able to do this. i tried seeing if youtube uses http instead of https as you suggested but even though i logged out it still used https.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YouTube is now forcing https via 301 redirection. Sometime ago it was not the case. Redirection was just a user setting stored in cookie.

You can try changing your User Agent and/or test on m.youtube.com but the traffic measurements may not be accurate since it's different domain and protocol and youtube can have separate priorities.

Changing User Agent is simple in Chrome Dev Tools (phone icon in top left corner).

Comment: But when I go to `http://youtube.com`, not logged in, I can video video with a simple HTTP connection. Or does that never apply to I-frame API?

Comment: What browser are you using? I tried Firefox and Chrome and both even in "privacy" mode redirect to https no matter what.

Comment: Ah, then they must've changed that, literally, within the last few days and I didn't get that 301 until now. You're right, it does that.

Comment: I can't find any official information about this but `curl -I http://youtube.com` does not lie ;-)